# Devolver true o false si un número está en un rango usando switch

Tags: javascript, switch

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que me piden que utilice switch y devuelva si un número es <50 y >20 pero después de escribir:

```js
function estaEnRango(numero){
  switch(numero){
    case < 50: {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Me sale `unexpected token '<'`

Comment: ¿Qué lenguaje estás ocupando?

Comment: ricardo-dlc  
javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se podría también poner `true` como expresión a evaluar en el `switch`, y la comparación en el `case`. Me parece que de este modo el código es menos redundante, más claro y más conforme al propósito para el cual existe `switch ... case`:

```js
function estaEnRango(numero) {
  switch (true) {
    case (numero > 20 && numero < 50):
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

console.log(estaEnRango(23));
console.log(estaEnRango(1));
```

Si el anterior código tiene que ser usado para verificar rangos de edad por ejemplo, sólo hay que agregar los case para cada rango, lo cual indica que poner la condición en los `case` sería la forma natural de resolver este caso:

```js
function estaEnRango(edad) {
  switch (true) {
    case edad >= 0 && edad <= 10:
      return "Niño";
      break;

    case edad >= 10 && edad <= 20:
      return "Adolescente";
      break;

    case edad >= 20 && edad <= 30:
      return "Joven";
      break;

    case edad > 30 && edad <= 120:
      return "Adulto";
      break;

    case edad > 120:
      return "¡Matusalén!";
      break;

    default:
      return `${edad}, un valor no válido en cuanto a la edad`;
      break;
  }
}

console.log(`Eres ${estaEnRango(23)}`);
console.log(`Eres ${estaEnRango(1)}`);
console.log(`Eres ${estaEnRango(34)}`);
console.log(`Eres ${estaEnRango(14)}`);
console.log(`Eres ${estaEnRango(99)}`);
console.log(`Eres ${estaEnRango(850)}`);
console.log(`Eres ${estaEnRango('fake')}`);
```

Comment: A. Cedano Muchas gracias

Answer (score 6):

El problema está en que [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) solo evalua el resultado de una única expresión y compara ese resultado con valores ya establecidos o específicos.

> La declaración switch evalúa una expresión, comparando el valor de esa expresión con una instancia case, y ejecuta declaraciones asociadas a ese case, así como las declaraciones en los case que siguen.

Debido a lo anterior, la expresión debe ir colocada en el `switch` y los posibles resultados deben estar colocados dentro de un `case`. En este caso los posibles resultados son `true` o `false` puesto que `numero` o está en rango o no lo está. Dado que el único valor que interesa es `true` el otro valor lo podemos obviar con `default`.

```js
function estaEnRango(numero) {
  switch (numero > 20 && numero < 50) {
    case true:
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

console.log(estaEnRango(20) ? 'Está en rango' : 'No está en rango');
console.log(estaEnRango(21) ? 'Está en rango' : 'No está en rango');
console.log(estaEnRango(49) ? 'Está en rango' : 'No está en rango');
console.log(estaEnRango(50) ? 'Está en rango' : 'No está en rango');
```

Si quieres evitar estar evaluando cada vez si devuelves `true` o `false`, podrías colocar el `console.log` dentro de la función evaluadora.

```js
function estaEnRango(numero) {
  switch (numero > 20 && numero < 50) {
    case true:
      console.log('Está en rango');
      break;
    default:
      console.log('No está en rango')
      break;
  }
}


estaEnRango(20);
estaEnRango(21);
estaEnRango(49);
estaEnRango(50);
```

Comment: ricardo-dlc Muchas gracias